# Improving score accuracy for multi class classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm working on a multi-class text classification project.

My goal is simple: given a "bug", I'd like to predict to which final group owner it will be assigned to.

I've 6 classes overall and I can't pass the 80% score - which is maybe not bad, but I'm aiming higher.

I was able to extract ~17000 samples of bugs and ended up with the below features (all text):

1. Subject
2. Description
3. Comments
4. Has images (boolean field) ==> ('yes' or 'no')
5. Involved groups ==> Not sure I can use it as it being derived from
   the comments
6. Committer groups
7. Reporter group
8. Assignee group

There're some features I'm not sure I'm allowed to use since they may not be available during prediction (comments for instance) and emitting them reduces the score to around 70%.

My process is:

1. Collecting the bugs
2. Cleaning the data ==> remove stop words and lemmatizing each feature
3. Since some features are absent, I'm filling them using prediction as well
4. Eventually using `XGBClassifier` for prediction (tried many others as well).

My question is what can I do more to improve the accuracy score?

**UPDATE:**

Adding some more info:

```
Mean Accuracy: 0.7930
Mean Precision: 0.7804
Mean Recall: 0.7913
XGBClassifier: score is 79%
```

So I guess my F1 score is:

```
In [1]: 2*(0.7804*0.7913)/(0.7804+0.7913)
Out[1]: 0.7858122033466947
```

Bottom line - pretty close to the initial score

Comment: Be careful that accuracy masks the differences between classes, a confusion matrix or (macro) precision/recall/f1-score would be a useful information here. Also your step 3 seems strange, do you mean that you first predict some of the features using another model?

Comment: @Erwan I'll add this benchmark data as well - the reason I didn't do it is because I've pretty much the same results.
Regarding step #3 - I've read somewhere I can complete missing data based by splitting my datafame to null/not-null subsets and predict the data using the not-null subset - this is exactly what I did.